# What is a correct punctuation for a sentence starting with "One more thing"?

Tags: punctuation, commas, dashes, colons

In the following sentence what would be the correct punctuation

> One more thing don't tell anyone about our conversation.

Should "One more thing" be separated by comma, dash or colon? Or perhaps nothing at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest and the one I would prefer is to treat it as two sentences:

> One more thing. Don't tell anyone about our conversation (on the subject of this and that ...)

This also gives you the facility to maneuver the second part.

Where the second part is short, and more important, use a colon to direct attention:

> One more thing: don't tell her.

Where the whole thing is rather simple and short, just include a comma:

> One more thing, it's better you don't tell her.

---

[EDIT] additional info, the *em dash*.
An em dash (—) may also be used: it serves the same purpose as the comma, with a supposedly stronger effect.

> One more thing — don't tell anyone about our conversation.

Comment: The last example is ungrammatical and appropriate only for bestsellers and informal writing where punctuation and grammar don't count for anything. It's called a **comma splice** and seems to be as popular as kitsch (e.g., the Mona Lisa on a coffee cup or any painting by Keene -- children with monstrously "darling" big round eyes), which the masses devour as if it were manna in the aesthetic deserts of their iPod lives.

Comment: +1 I agree two sentences is best. What about a hyphen?

Comment: @Urbycoz Not a hyphen (-) but an em dash (—) may be used. It serves the same purpose as the comma, with a supposedly stronger effect.

Answer (score 1):

A sentence like that would not be appropriate in formal writing at all. If you are reporting it as direct speech, a comma after *thing* would represent more or less accurately the way it might have been delivered.

Comment: I'm interested in a situation when it used in a sort of playful text

Comment: Then punctuate it in a way that you think makes it look playful, and use smileys, lots of asterisks and exclamation marks and Comic Sans MS font.

Comment: Seems that punctuation in English is exactly "punctuate it in a way that you like", which makes it harder to master.

Comment: There is a school of thought that punctuation is not part of grammar but "style". And "style" is a matter of, well you see, style. :)

Comment: "not ... at all" seems a little strong. It would certainly not be out of place in a formal spoken text - The X Lectures sort of thing - and I think would not be deprecated in formal written texts in the humanities. It's a useful marker for your knock-out punch in a complex argument.

Comment: English grammar is all about the rules for speaking English, not writing it. There is no punctuation in speech, only pauses, pitch, stress, intonation, volume, etc. Punctuation is, indeed, not a part of grammar at all but a matter of writing mechanics, which is ruled by convention and a variety of style manuals and grammar handbooks. Style is a legitimate criterion for which punctuation to use (if any at all) when writing informally or creatively, but not when writing formal prose for publication -- at least, that's what most publishers and copy editors think.

Answer (score 0):

Three possibilities:

> **One more thing. Don't tell...**

,

> **One more thing: Don't tell...**

, and

> **One more thing — don't tell...**

All three are fine in informal writing. I prefer the first.

Comment: I prefer the second. I probably overuse the colon, but it's the only conjunctive point we've got.

Answer (score 0):

"One more thing." is not a complete sentence.  Therefore, it should not be followed by a period or a semicolon.  Remember that a semicolon connects two stand-alone sentences that make more sense together.

I agree that if the second clause is more important, then you should definitely use a colon.  However, the longer a clause is, the more ease can be gained from varying your punctuation.  If your sentence is shorter, you can easily get away with using a comma.  If your sentence is longer, or contains a list which must be separated with commas, you should use a colon.

The em dash is very useful in this case, since there is often a much more prominent break between the clauses when using this phrase.

In formal writing, "One more thing" as a clause by itself should not be used.  Instead, you could write "There is one more thing." or "..., because of one more thing." or something of the like, in which case you can use a period or semicolon.